# How to correctly instance the volume cloud RawShaderMaterial?

Tags: three.js

In essence the question is simply how to create an instanced mesh from the geometry/material in this example:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cloud#webgl2_volume_cloud

There are a couple previous questions on the forum which highlight issues people have had instancing a mesh with RawShaderMaterial, however [the answer prisoner849](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-can-i-use-instancedmesh-with-rawshadermaterial/36963) provided (https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/oNpMBpR) resolves this.

Unfortunately that same implementation does not work for the volume cloud and I've not been able to ascertain where the issue lies - perhaps due to the WebGL2 prerequisite?

Many thanks!

The functioning implementation by Prisoner849 FYI:

```
let m = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
   vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
   fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent
});

let im = new THREE.InstancedMesh(g, material, MAX_COUNT);
let dummy = new THREE.Object3D();
for (let i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT; i++) {
   dummy.position.x = i * 2;
   dummy.updateMatrix();
   im.setMatrixAt(i, dummy.matrix);
   im.setColorAt(i, new THREE.Color(Math.random() * 0xffffff));
}
scene.add(im);
```